# Mysql :Exclude row that does not satisfy the condition list

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So Here is My data

```
ID  C1        C2               C3  
6             Digit 2          6,8,10,12
12            Digit 3          15
15  127       Digit 2          6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
68  140,141   Digit 11         85,86,87,88,167,168,158,159
73  1         Digit 11         85,86,87,88,169,170
76            Digit 11         85,86,87,91,164,165,166,167,168
99            Digit 11         20,27,85,86,87
106           Digit 1          1,2
111           Digit 11         85,86,87,88
112           Digit 11         85,86,87,88
135           Digit 11         85,86,87
```

and my condition string is (2,6,15,37,42,52,62,65,79,85,94,100,104,107,113,124,131)

Now,I want to exclude row 3,4,5 if the values 127,140,141,1 are not in the list condition. I tried Not in , but no avail. I think I might be missing something basic, but just cant get it.

Comment: Using PHP might make this really easy if you're willing to learn about that.

Comment: Who designed this table? If it was you, then you need to redesign it.

Comment: this just a result set that i get from another table; also I am using these with Windows Forms

Comment: If this is your result set, then paste the normalized data.

Comment: Its pretty much the same, Not normalized data.how can I redesign the Table. Fairly New to SQL. Thanks

Comment: If you thought any of the answers were good you should give them an upvote. I don't know if you are allowed to since you're a new user, though. But I think you do have the ability to click on the checkmark for best answer. Then if you have further questions, you can post them in a new question.

Comment: @user1396792 Wow, no upvotes, no best answer? I hope you don't plan on asking any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to store multiple values in a column if possible. Then it's easier to do queries like this.

You cannot use "IN" or "NOT IN" because they are looking for a list of separate items. But C3 is just one item that happens to have commas in it.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ID, C1, C2, CONCAT('|',REPLACE(C3,',','|'),'|') as C3 FROM `table` WHERE `C3` ) as t1

WHERE t1.C3 NOT LIKE "|127|" AND t1.C3 NOT LIKE "|140|" AND t1.C3 NOT LIKE "|141|" AND t1.C3 NOT LIKE "|1|"
```

You could avoid the "|" and just concat "," to the start and end.

Or you could fix your database schema so that it actually acts like a Normalized Relational Database.

Every column that contains multiple values should be separated out into its own table.

There should be no column `C3` in your table above. Instead, you should have a table, `some_other_data`:

At this point, I see that C3=6 is related to more than one record in the main table. Therefore, you actually need a third, linking table, in addition to `some_other_data`. See below.

```
`some_other_data`
id
6
8
10
12
15

`main_table_to_some_other_data_link`
some_other_data_id | main_table_id
6                    6
8                    6
10                   6
12                   6
15                   12
6                    15
```

etc. You can see that the linking table can contain duplicates of either value. But your other two tables would have completely unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

(I'm assuming you can change your table structure.  If you can't someone else will need to address your question.)

The long lists of comma-separated data are a flag that they have a one-to-many relationship with `ID`.

For example, make the data in `C3` its own table:

```
ID   MainID   C3
================
 1      6      6
 2      6      8
 3      6     10
 4      6     12
 5     12     15
 6     15      6
 7     15      7
 8     15      8
 9     15      9
10     15     10
11     15     11
12     15     12
13     15     13
// and so forth //
```

So ID is the primary key of the new table, `MainID` is the foreign key that refers to the record in your primary table, and `C3` is the data in C3.

Each separate value of C3 now has its own record.

Now, you're in a position to use something like

```
Select * from MainTable
    Inner Join NewTable
    On MainTable.ID = NewTable.MainID
    Where NewTable.C3 Not In (2,6,15,37,42,52,62,65,79,85,94,100,104,107,113,124,131);
```

If you can, pulling out the one-to-many relationships into their own tables will make things easier for you.